# Is it possible to receive a pointer to C function in Rust and call it back?

Tags: c++, c, rust

I'm learning about interfacing Rust and C++ (using the C interface). This is an example from Mozilla's guide for Rust on Android:

```
use std::os::raw::{c_char};
use std::ffi::{CString, CStr};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_greeting(to: *const c_char) -> *mut c_char {
    let c_str = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(to) };
    let recipient = match c_str.to_str() {
        Err(_) => "there",
        Ok(string) => string,
    };

    CString::new("Hello ".to_owned() + recipient).unwrap().into_raw()
}
```

as you can see, a C char pointer is expected, and it returns a C char pointer also.

I want to use a Rust code as a library on my project. This Rust code will deliver packets to me when they're ready. Therefore, I need a way to pass a callback to Rust so it can call it back when it has data. Kinda like this C++ snippet:

```
extern "C" onData(uint8_t* payload, size_t size) {
    //do something with payload
}

MyRustType myRustObject("initialization_string");
myRustObject.setOnDataCallback(&onData);
myRustObject.beginWork();
```

So, the rust 'class', `MyRustType`, will begin to work and deliver packets through `onData`. Is it possible to pass a C function as a pointer to Rust?

If not, I can pass the pointer as an `uint64_t` number, and make Rust pass this number + payload back to a C function, which in turn casts this uint64_t pointer into the function and calls it with the payload. But I think that since Rust is so C-friendly, there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Just use the function pointer type `unsafe extern "C" fn()`?

Comment: @Veedrac I don't know about this pointer. You mean I can simply do `unsafe extern "C" functionName(uint8_t* payload, size_t size)`? (do rust have size_t?). And can I do like this: `fn registerCallbackFromC(unsafe extern "C" functionName(uint8_t* payload, size_t size) myFunction)`? You understand what I mean? I need to pass the callback as an argument to Rust

Comment: C's `size_t` is Rust's `usize`. Yes to the rest, I believe, though the syntax is `fn registerCallbackFromC(my_fun: unsafe extern "C" fn(uint8_t* payload, size_t size))`.

Comment: Actually it would be something like: `extern "C" fn registerCallbackFromC(payload: *mut u8, size: usize) -> c_int`. Do not forget the `mut` is the callback is allowed to modify the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call freely, but unsafely, from C to Rust and from Rust to C.

From Rust to C: write a `extern "C"` block with the prototypes of the C functions.

From C to Rust: write the Rust function with a `#[no_mangle] extern "C"` prefix. You must ensure that any value received or returned is FFI friendly: basic types or `repr(C)` types or raw pointers to those and a few others.

Also you will need the equivalent C declarations to those of Rust. for that you can use the types in `std::os::raw`, `std::ffi` and the external crate `libc`.

Particularly, the answer to your questions about function pointers, a type such as this in C:

```
typedef int (*callback)(uint8_t *data, size_t len);
```

is translated into Rust as:

```
type Callback = unsafe extern "C" fn(data: *mut u8, len: usize) -> c_int;
```

This type `Callback` is FFI friendly, so you can store it, pass between Rust and C, and call it whenever you want. And of course you can use it as argument or return type in other FFI declarations:

```
int do_the_thing(uint8_t*data, size_t len, callback cb);
```

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn do_the_thing(
    data: *const u8, len: usize,
    cb: Option<Callback>) -> c_int)
{
    //...
}
```

Remember that in Rust pointer functions are non-nullable, so if you want C to be able to pass `NULL` you use `Option<fn>`.

For more details about FFI in Rust you can read [this chapter of the Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible tha you add how to compile?

Comment: Compilation? There was nothing about compilation in your question either. Anyways, that would depend on wether you are linking a C library into a Rust program or a Rust library into a C program. I think you want the latter, so it basically goes down to setting up your crate as a `cdylib` and setting up your C compiling framework to call `cargo build` and link the resulting library. If you need more details, you should probably create a new question.